# Add Shadow Effect on Hover to DIV boxes

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, shadow

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to make it so that upon hovering over each separate box on the front page of my website (http://thefloodplains.com/), a shadow animation occurs for that specific box. I want it to look very similar to what can be found at this page: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/. I've used this page as a guide in an attempt to set up a hover shadow effect.

Here's the CSS/HTML specifically for the div boxes on my web page (http://thefloodplains.com/):

```
.col-md-4 {
    color:#00A5D1;
    height:300px;
}

.col-md-3 {
    color:#00A5D1;
    height:300px;
    box-shadow: 2 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0.1, 0.1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
    transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.col-md-4:hover {
    background-color: #FFE097;
}
.col-md-3:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25, 1.25);
    }

.col-md-4 h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.col-md-4 {
    color:#00A5D1;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid #FF8B6F;
    position: relative;
}

.col-md-3 {
    height:300px;
    position: relative;
}

.col-md-4:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  background: #FFE097;
  opacity: 0;
}

.col-md-3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;    
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.col-md-4:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.col-md-3:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.col-md-4 h3 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Anything with the class ".col-md-3" is where I have attempted to add in the hover-shadow effects (in much the same way that I already have the current hover-color effects set up). The following code is the rest of the CSS/HTML of my front page:

```
<style>
    h3 {
        font-size:36px;
        font-style: bold;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:'Buernard', Garamond, "Buenard", "EB Garamond",'EB Garamond';
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;   
    }
    #div1 {
            background-image: url('AboutIcon.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div2 {
            background-image: url('ArticlesIcon.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div3 {
            background-image: url('CodingBrackets2.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div4 {
            background-image: url('ContactIcon.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: contain; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div5 {
            background-image: url('FSMusicArt.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div6 {
            background-image: url('AudioProduction4.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div7 {
            background-image: url('Violin3.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div8 {
            background-image: url('GalleryImage2.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    #div9 {
            background-image: url('Handshake2.png');
            background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
            background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
    }
    div {
        background-image:url(../images/please-dont-use-spaces.jpg); //add the background image
        background-position: center center; //center the image in the div
        background-size: cover; //cover the entire div
    }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <a href="About.html" title="About the site and Author"><div class="col-md-4" id='div1'>
                    <h3>About</h3>
                    </div></a>
                <a href="Articles.html" title="Original Articles and Content"><div class="col-md-4" id='div2'>
                    <h3>Articles</h3>
                </div>
                <a href="CodingCorner.html" title="Coding Corner - Code for a Variety of Projects"><div class="col-md-4" id="div3">
                    <h3>Coding Corner</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="Contact-Social.html" title="Contact The Floodplains & The FloodShark"><div class="col-md-4" id="div4">
                  <h3>Contact & Social</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="TheFloodSharkMain.html" title="The FloodShark Music and Media"><div class="col-md-4" id="div5">
                    <h3>
                    The FloodShark
                    Music
                    </h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="FloodplainProductions.html" title="Floodplain Productions - virtual record label"><div class="col-md-4" id="div6">
                    <h3>Floodplain Productions</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">   
                <a href="ClassicalCorner.html" title="Classical Corner - A nook dedicated to sharing and categorizing classical music"><div class="col-md-4" id="div7">
                    <h3>Classical Corner</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Gallery.html" title="Images, Photographs, and Album Art"><div class="col-md-4" id="div8">
                    <h3>Gallery</h3>
                </div></a>
                <a href="Contribute-Support.html" title="Contribute to The Floodplains!"><div class="col-md-4" id="div9">
                    <h3>Contribute / Support</h3>
                </div></a>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>
```

I tried adding "col-md-3" to the div's as a second class in the above code along with "col-md-4," which controls the color hover effect. The problem is, I don't think this method works, but I'm not really sure what does. As of right now, I'm using the "col-md-4" color hover effect - which is working - but getting a shadow effect to work simultaneously is something I have yet to figure out.

So currently - upon hovering - the boxes turn to that transparent shade of orange/yellow. Is there a way that I can get the shadow animation AND the color-change hovers to work together at the same time? So basically I just need a hover animation added to what is already here at http://thefloodplains.com/.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this, [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mc0szLj/)

I have added the style for `.col-md-4`. Please check the code...

Answer (score 8):

Create a new class for the effect i.e. **hovernow** add the following code:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.hovernow {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hovernow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="hovernow">

</div>
```

Then add this class `.hovernow` to the div's which you like the **hover** effect to apply to.